# US Freelancer working for New Zealand company

Tags: taxes

I am aware there are many other questions like this one, but from what I've seen the answer varies significantly based on which countries are involved. I'm a freelance contractor in the US, and I may soon be working with a New Zealand company. What are my tax obligations? I know of those intrinsic to working as an independent contractor in the US, but what changes or is added when the client is in New Zealand?

Comment: Then I guess you have also seen that every single one of those questions includes a "get an accountant, don't ask this stuff on a forum, too important to rely on shoddy advice" answer?

Comment: Never saw one of those. I saw a whole bunch of actual answers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

US taxes are based upon **US INCOME**. Where that income originates is irrelevant.

You live and work in the US... you drive on US roads... your children (if you have any) go to US schools... you pay US taxes on all money you earn, even if that income originates from outside the US or even Earth.

In many respects, as an example, it's similar to state taxes. If you live in State A you pay State A taxes on your income, even if you have a client living in State B. You *don't* pay taxes in State B just because a client happens to live in State B.

The *only* difference with overseas clients is the rate of exchange for the currency. If you charge $10 US the client sends you $10US, that means they are actually spending roughly $15 NZD. You still earn $10 US dollars though. So you pay taxes on the $10 US dollars you earned.

So, in this case, don't let the client talk you into receiving NZD... you'll make **less**. Make it clear that all invoices are in US Dollars. If you don't and the client sends you that $10 as NZD, you'll only earn ~$7.

And yeah.. hire an accountant. Or even just find one you can connect with from time to time to bounce stuff off of if needed.

Comment: Okay, so to clarify New Zealand doesn't charge the employer any taxes on my income? That's what seemed odd.

Comment: Huh? Employer?? What's that got to do with Freelancing?? Freelancing doesn't have "employers".

Comment: Employer, client, in freelancing it's the same thing, or so I thought? This company is employing me as a contractor to do XYZ work.

Comment: No "Employer" is **not** the same as "client"  in the eyes of the law (and taxes [US]). In addition, "employers'  generally **must** offer things like health benefits, vacation days, sick leave, etc. And **all your work** for an "employer" would be "work-for-hire" and you may not wish to relinquish your intellectual property under that arrangement.

Comment: Alright. But back to the point, New Zealand wouldn't want to claim any taxes based on the fact that my client is there?

Comment: Who cares? If the NZ company needs to pay taxes in NZ that's their issue. You, not living in NZ, would never owe NZ taxes.

Comment: This thread just shows you really do need an accountant. Not just to be flippant, you'll think back on this thread in a few years when you are either fucked because you didnt get an accountant, or very happy because you did and he helped you out.